# How do I remove employees who have turned 18 - mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause, date-arithmetic

```
SELECT birthday
FROM employees
WHERE ((DATEDIFF(Year,birthday())>'18')
```

Comment: `birthday` is a column, not a function. `DATEDIFF` has 3 arguments, not 2.

Comment: You should provide the error or unexpected behaviour you are having. The structure for the table would also help.

Comment: @madtyn  The deletion has already succeeded, but it deletes the unit value even though there are several employees who have 18 years of age Do you have an idea of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can use date arithmetics:

```
select * from employee where birthdate + interval 18 year <= current_date
```

This filters out employees that are 18 years old or more as of today.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATE_SUB](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) function:

```
SELECT birthday
FROM employees
WHERE birthday < DATE_SUB(curdate(), interval 18 year);
```

[SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=21ed5c799ba3a92466026ac9ce3ae432&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql80)